# I need to modify my WinSCP script to only download files of specific file extensions

Tags: powershell, ftp, winscp, winscp-net

I have a script that calls the WinSCP .NET assembly. The script downloads the most recent files from an FTP directory and names them based on the their file extension + `.txt` (`2245.xml` -> `xml.txt`).

I need to create a filter to only download file extensions named `tn*` or `nc1`. Can anyone point me in the right direction:

```
$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session

# Connect
$session.Open($sessionOptions)

# Get list of files in the directory
$directoryInfo = $session.ListDirectory($remotePath)

# Select the most recent file
$latest = $directoryInfo.Files |
    Where-Object { -Not $_.IsDirectory} | 
    Group-Object { [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($_.Name) } | 
    ForEach-Object{ 
        $_.Group | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select -First 1
    }

$extension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($latest.Name)
"GetExtension('{0}') returns '{1}'" -f $fileName, $extension

if ($latest -eq $Null)
{
    Write-Host "No file found"
    exit 1
}

# Download

$latest | ForEach-Object {
    $extension = ([System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($_.Name)).Trim(".")
    $session.GetFiles($session.EscapeFileMask($remotePath + $_.Name), "$localPath\$extension.txt" ).Check()
}
```

I tried adding a filter in the directory sorting but that didn't work:

```
    Where-Object { -Not $_.IsDirectory -or [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($_.Name) -like "tn*" -or [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($_.Name) -eq "nc1"} |
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost correct. Just just need to:

- `-and` the extension condition with "not directory" condition. Or use two separate `Where-Object` clauses as I do below.
- The `GetExtension` result includes the dot.

```
$latest = $directoryInfo.Files |
    Where-Object { -Not $_.IsDirectory } | 
    Where-Object {
        [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($_.Name) -eq ".nc1" -or
        [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($_.Name) -like ".tn*"
    } |
    Group-Object { [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($_.Name) } | 
    ForEach-Object { 
        $_.Group | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select -First 1
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for all your help Martin